# XAML: Creating a DataTemplate for a ViewModel represented in an Expander

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, datatemplate, expander

Let´s say I have a custom control similar to Expander and will be showing multiple types of objects in that expander. I want to define a DataTemplate for each type of object.

Now I want to show specific information when it's not expanded and something else when it is.

Normally with expander it only shows whatever is bound to the Header property.

Can I somehow define two areas in the DataTemplate for each view?

Is there perhaps some other brilliant way to do this?

Comment: So if I understand this correctly, instead of this expanding and collapsing, it's really toggling between showing the same data in 2 different ways?

Comment: @Joel Yes you could say that. It could also be seen as a Header with more info then just a single property. I'm actually going to apply this style to a ListBox and have the selectedItem become expanded while others show the most relevant information.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ExpanderItemDataTemplate">
        <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
            <Grid x:Name="ExpandedContent" />
            <Grid x:Name="CollapsedContent" />
        </Grid>
        <DataTemplate.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:YourCustomControl}}"
                         Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="ExpandedContent"
                        Value="Visible" />
                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="CollapsedContent"
                        Value="Collapse" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:YourCustomControl}}"
                         Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="ExpandedContent"
                        Value="Collapse" />
                <Setter Property="Visibility"
                        TargetName="CollapsedContent"
                        Value="Visible" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </DataTemplate.Triggers>
```

Comment: So I would create one of these for each type I would use and add the correct View into each gridrow? Could work. BTW are you Icelandic (Eyjafjallajökull)?

Comment: I'm not, but I really liked this word.

Comment: Could I do this the other way around? Having the triggers in the control and having them target a named area inside a dataTemplate that will be bound? That's what I would really wan't to do.

Answer (score 1):

Have you considered simply use a `TabControl` ?
You could for example add two tabs and style them. Here is the code for tab styling:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabPanel}">
        <!--Whatever you need for tab position (here center) -->
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center" />
    </Style>
```

and

```
           <ControlTemplate x:Key="TabItemTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <!-- Place whatever control you want for design (grid, dockpanel... -->
                <!-- And then the triggers you'd need for, here, color if selected or not, as an example -->
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="Blue" />
                    </Trigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="False">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                    </Trigger>

                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
```

This is the natural way I'd think about it.
You coult extend this code to, for example, add a trigger changing the selected tab when you click on the only visible tab.
Anyway, the behavior you're describing seems more to fit with a `TabControl` than an `Expander`

Comment: Thanks for the advice, If I would mess around with this enough it could work, but I wouldn't wan't to have the actual tabs so it would perhaps be easier just to start out with Itemscontrol.